# Proof with total probability theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

How can I prove that inequality by using total probability theorem?

$$\min\left\{ P(a|b), P(a|b’) \right\} \leq P(a) \leq \max\left\{ P(a|b), P(a|b’)\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(a)=P(a|b)P(b)+P(a|b')P(b')\leq \max \{P(a|b),P(a|b')\} P(b)+\max \{P(a|b),P(a|b')\} P(b')$$ $$=\max \{P(a|b),P(a|b')\}$$ since $P(b)+P(b')=1$.  The left hand inequality is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $P(a)<P(a\mid b)$ and $P(a)<P(a\mid b^c)$.

Then because at least one of $P(b)$ and $P(b^c)$ is positive: $$P(a)=P(a\mid b)P(b)+P(a\mid b^c)P(b^c)>P(a)P(b)+P(a)P(b^c)=P(a)$$ which is absurd.

Draw conclusions concerning minimum.

Same idea can be used for maximum.